# Checking if %Y exists in current file in VimScript

Tags: conditional-statements, vim

Like the title says.

I would love to know how, with VimScript, I can do an if statement, that checks if %Y (for statusline) exists in the current file. This is what I have so far:

```
if expand('%:Y') != ""
    let filetype=extend('%:Y')
    let filetype+= ",\ "
else
    let filetype=""
endif
```

This is, of course, for my statusline, for which I don't want to show the filetype comma and space if the filetype doesn't exist.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `expand()` or similar to resolve options in `'statusline'`; they are only interpreted inside the setting.

If you don't like the formatting returned by the option or want to combine options to a custom indicator, you have to emulate the option in a `%{...}` Vimscript expression. Most options can be completely or mostly emulated. For your `%Y`, this would be included in `'statusline'` instead:

```
let &statusline .= '%{empty(&filetype) ? "" : "," . toupper(&filetype) . ", "}'
```

Instead of putting a large expression inline, you can also move it to a separate `:function`.

Comment: This is great! Although I tried it, and it gives me some error. Vim's been crashing since then so I'm not sure what the error is. Something about an unfinished something.

Comment: BTW, my computer was FUBAR'ed on me, so I'm doing this through my phone. I'll try this in a couple of days, again, in the mean time, you think you could look into that error for me?